# Unauthorized to call API deployed to Azure

Tags: python, azure, api, flask

I build API for image recognition, I tested it locally and it is working perfectly.
I deploy it to Azure but when try to call it, the same way as local version it give me this error:

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

API is hosted on Azure Web App service, I am also hosting other site on this service and it is not requiring any credentials.

API code:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def main():

    data = {"Success": False}
    data['Catalog'] = ""

    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        if flask.request.files.get('image'):
            image = flask.request.files['image'].read()
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))

            image = prepare_image(image, target=img_size)

            images_path = './images'
            X, y = loadimgs(images_path)

            embedding_model = load_model('./triplet_loss_model_100.h5')

            example_emb = embedding_model.predict(image)
            embedded_imgs = embedding_model.predict(X)

            dist = compute_dist(embedded_imgs, np.repeat(example_emb, embedded_imgs.shape[0], axis=0))
            index = np.argmin(dist)
            label_ = y[index]

            data['Catalog'] = label_[0]
            data['Success'] = True

        return flask.jsonify(data)
```

I tried to call api using curl and postman, both are giving the same error.

Comment: when are you getting the error? while uploading the file? 
Note: It looks like you are storing the file in the file system. it's not recommended to use file system in azure app service. It's recommended to use Azure Storage

Comment: How have you configured your Authentication and Authorisation?

Comment: @Prawin I am sending file in call body, as form-data

Comment: @PGHE I did not do it. As i mention it was not necessary in my second hosted service, so I think it is not necessary in this one

Comment: @psowa001, can you check if other end points are working without the 401 error?

Comment: @psowa001, did you ever get past this?  I'm experiencing a very similar situation.